# Remove product count in category page sidebar

Tags: magento2, product, category

I have a Pearl WeltPixel theme for my Magento site and I would like to remove the number of products next to the category name in the sidebar. But even putting "no" in display the number of products in layered navigation and then refresh the cache, the numbers are still displayed, I don't know how to do that.

I want to remove the numbers here :

[image]

Comment: Create custom module and override category page and comment code from where count is used

Comment: @ZahidH Thank you for your answer, how do I make a custom module of the category page? and I already tried to comment count code but nothing change even in flush the cache and reindex

Comment: How to create module in magento2: url : (https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)
create moduel according to your needs and show me screen shot where you had commented code count...

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to disable the count in the Magento admin store configuration.

Navigate to the below path.

> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> find 'Layered Navigation' then
> set -> Display Product Count to No

[image]

Comment: I tried but even refreshing the cache and doing a reindex nothing happened. It may be because I have a theme installed on it, right?

Comment: Yes, that might be a issue, you need to compare your theme file with the magento core to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS way also to hide the count from filters.

add below CSS in your theme store head section by editing Content-> Configuration -> edit your store, In HTML Head section add below CSS in  Scripts and Style Sheets.

```
.catalog-category-view .filter-content .filter-options .filter-options-item .filter-options-content ol li a .count{
    display: none;
}
```

Flush your cache and check.